# How to get a JTextField to respond to the enter key

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener, enter

So I want to get a JTexField to put the text in it into a JTextArea when the enter key is pressed with the cursor in it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Forget about using `KeyListener` for `Swing` components.

This listener was designed for use with `AWT` components does not provide a reliable interaction mechanism for `JTextComponents`.

Use an `ActionListener` instead - on the vast majority of systems an `ActionEvent` is dispatched by the `JTextField` when enter is pressed.

```
myTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       myTextArea.append(myTextField.getText() + "\n");
    }
});
```

Comment: but how do i make it specific to the enter key?

Comment: `ActionListener` is triggered by the enter key for `JTextField`

Comment: The ActionEvent is triggered by the systems/look and feel "accept" action automatically. In most cases, this is the enter key

Answer (score 0):

```
    JTextArea myJTextArea = new JTextArea();
    myJTextArea.setBounds(200, 15, 258, 28);
    myJPanel.add(myJTextArea);

    JTextField myJTextField = new JTextField();
    myJTextField.setBounds(15, 15, 130, 28);
    myJPanel.add(myJTextField);
    myJTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                myJTextArea.setText(myJTextField.getText());
            }
        }
    });
```