# JTextField not updating user input in for-loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jlabel, jtextfield

My for loop is not updating, I'm getting the output "mmmmmm" or "ffffff" of the same letter the user inputs each time. I want it to constantly update the next letter each time like this:

user input: m
user input: f
user input: d

output: "Letters Used: mfd"

```
int j = 0;  
String []used = new String[6];  
for(j = 0; j<6; j++){  
    used[j] = tf.getText(); //get user input  
}  
jl2.setText("Letters Used:    " + used[0] + used[1] + used[2] + used[3] + used[4] + used[5] );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a for-loop for this. [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) has built in callbacks for text changes with [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html):

```
tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {          // text was changed
        jl2.setText("Letters Used:    " + tf.getText());
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}          // text was deleted
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}          // text was inserted
});
```

---

***Update:***

If you want to only respond on `Enter` presses, you can use an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) [which is called on `Enter` presses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16378927/1290264):

```
jl2.setText("Letters Used:    ");

tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        jl2.setText(jl2.getText() + tf.getText());
    }
});
```

***Note:*** Actually, `ActionEvent` is triggered by the system's look and feel "accept" action. In most cases, this is the enter key.

Comment: I want to make it so when 'enter' is pressed, the letter entered is displayed in the JLabel and is constantly adding the next letter entered. With the document listener the text entered is being displayed live so when the letter entered is erased, it is also being erased from the JLabel

Comment: +1 for the ActionListener, but use the `Document.insertString(...)` method to append the text instead of using the setText() method.

Comment: +1 for the additional `Note` and `Update` that make the answer more thorough.