# When sending message with keylistener "enter" why do I get and extra linebreak?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

[github link](https://github.com/AEkman/QuizApplication/blob/master/src/ClientController.java)

When pressing enter I want to send message via event using FXML:

```
textFieldInput.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
    try {
        if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)  {
                String text = textFieldInput.getText();
                send(text);
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        textFieldInput.setText("message not sent! -something went wrong... \n");
    }
});
```

Send function:

```
public void send(String message) {
    try {
        output.println(ClientController.USERNAME + ": " + message);
        output.flush();
        textFieldInput.clear();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        output.println("message not sent! -something went wrong... \n");
    }
}
```

My problem is that after i send a message the program adds another "keystroke" so my return key gets hit again and adds a new line to the textField area. I don't see why and where?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the first examples are supposed to represent. Could you be a bit more clear in the description please?

Comment: Please edit the question with your response: don't put it in the comments.

Comment: Untested I'd guess that you're combining AWT & Swing. Have a look at this article and rethink your solution. Maybe this will work better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378888/how-to-get-a-jtextfield-to-respond-to-the-enter-key

Comment: I'm using javafx and FXML.

Comment: updated question

Comment: I believe the text field itself listens for key released events, which obviously happen after key pressed events. So the default behavior will be invoked after your handler. If this is a text field, though, why are you using a listener for key events, instead of a listener for [action events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty)?

Comment: FXML wont let me setOnAction to the textArea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use KeyEvent to prevent enter key using below code.**

```
textFieldInput.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if (event.isControlDown()) {
            KeyEvent newEvent= new KeyEvent(null, null, null, null, false, false, false, false);
            textFieldInput.fireEvent(newEvent);
        }
        event.consume();
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            send(textFieldInput.getText());
        }

    });
```

Comment: Well that sorta worked, though now i can't erase text and my send message  only prints the text to console but doesn't seem to send it to socket for some reason.

Comment: Hmm, found the real issue, I hade mixed up textArea with textField and that was the reason I couldn't use setOnAction among other things.