# Java JTextField as InputStream. 'ENTER' not functioning as enter

Tags: java, ssh, inputstream, jtextfield, outputstream

My program connects to UNIX/PUTTY in order to execute commands through a custom GUI. I have a JTextArea as my OutputStream and a JTextField as my InputStream.

The Output is functioning as expected, however Input stream is not. In order for the command to be executed within UNIX it requires the ENTER key to be pressed, however the enter key is not functioning as expected.

Here is my code:

```
public class JTextFieldInputStream extends InputStream {
byte[] contents;
int pointer = 0;
String toBytes = "";
public JTextFieldInputStream(final JTextField text) {

    text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar()=='\n'){
                toBytes = text.getText()+'\n';
                contents = toBytes.getBytes();
                pointer = 0;
                text.setText("");
                toBytes = "";
            }
            super.keyReleased(e);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    if(pointer >= contents.length) return -1;
    return this.contents[pointer++];
}
```

I am trying to pass the '\n' char as the ENTER, but doesn't seem to be working. It gets into the if statement fine and will reset the text field to "". But '\n' toBytes () doesn't seem to be interpreted by the input stream as an enter press.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378888/how-to-get-a-jtextfield-to-respond-to-the-enter-key

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with JTextField as it is a Single lines only you need to use JTextArea in your case.

Comment: Didnt work :( With TextField moves on to the next line, however the input stream still does send that as an Enter press to UNIX